# How do I examine linear map on the linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = P_n$ be the vector space of the polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and let $B=\left \{1,x_0,...,x_n \right \}$ the canonical basis in the vector space of the polynomials.

How do I examine following linear map on the linearity?

$\varphi :P_n\rightarrow \mathbb{R},p\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}p(x)dx$

In the case of linearity, specify the matrix of the map with respect to the canonical bases of the given vector spaces, and determine the image and the nucleus of the image.

Comment: Hint: $$\int_0^1 (p(x)+q(x))\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^1 p(x)\ \mathsf dx+\int_0^1 q(x)\ \mathsf dx$$
and
$$ 
\int_0^1 x^n\ \mathsf dx = \frac1{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linearity we need to check that the map preserves sums and multiplication with scalars:

$$\varphi(p+q)=\int_0^1 (p+q)(x) dx=\int_0^1 p(x) + q(x) dx = \int_0^1 p(x)dx + \int_0^1 q(x)dx$$

$$\varphi(c \cdot p)=\int_0^1 c\cdotp(x)dx = c\int_0^1 p(x)dx$$
, so the requirements follow directly from linearity of integration.

To compute the matrix, we need to check the image of the basis elements under the map $\varphi$. We have that, assuming you mean that the basis is $B=\{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n \}$:

$$\varphi(x^n)=\int_0^1 x^n dx=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

so the (row) matrix will have these as columns: $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \dots, \frac{1}{n+1})$.

Since $\varphi(1)=1$, we have that the map is surjective (since $1$ is the only basis vector in $\mathbb{R}$), so the image is $\mathbb{R}$.

Finally, consider a polynomial $p=a_0+a_1x + \dots + a_nx^n$. Then

$$\varphi(p)=\int_0^1 p dx = \int_0^1 a_0 + a_1x + \dots + a_nx^n dx= a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{n+1}$$

so $\ker(\varphi)$ (the polynomials which are mapped to $0$) consists of those polynomials of the above form that satisfy
$$a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{n+1}=0.$$

I apologize if I made some errors in the above, it is pretty late and I am tired.

Comment: Wouldn't the kernel be the polynomials which are mapped to $0$?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, it's supposed to be 0. I'll edit it